# Rewrite blade from package Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

I need return other view with custom template. How I can do it?

I finded this method:

```
public function getIndex($group = null)
{
    $locales = $this->manager->getLocales();
    $groups = Translation::groupBy('group');
    $excludedGroups = $this->manager->getConfig('exclude_groups');
    if($excludedGroups){
        $groups->whereNotIn('group', $excludedGroups);
    }
    $groups = $groups->select('group')->orderBy('group')->get()->pluck('group', 'group');
    if ($groups instanceof Collection) {
        $groups = $groups->all();
    }
    $groups = [''=>'Choose a group'] + $groups;
    $numChanged = Translation::where('group', $group)->where('status', Translation::STATUS_CHANGED)->count();
    $allTranslations = Translation::where('group', $group)->orderBy('key', 'asc')->get();
    $numTranslations = count($allTranslations);
    $translations = [];
    foreach($allTranslations as $translation){
        $translations[$translation->key][$translation->locale] = $translation;
    }
     return view('translation-manager::index')
        ->with('translations', $translations)
        ->with('locales', $locales)
        ->with('groups', $groups)
        ->with('group', $group)
        ->with('numTranslations', $numTranslations)
        ->with('numChanged', $numChanged)
        ->with('editUrl', action('\Barryvdh\TranslationManager\Controller@postEdit', [$group]))
        ->with('deleteEnabled', $this->manager->getConfig('delete_enabled'));
}
```

How I can return my view? I need go in vendor?

Comment: Never modify vendor! Run `$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\TranslationManager\ManagerServiceProvider" --tag=views`. This will copy templates from vendor to the `resources/views/vendor/translation-manager` where you are free to do anything you want.

Comment: @Haru I know it. How I can integrate custom layout in this blade? I have layout of voyager admin, but if I do extends layout of voyager admin, then I get error undefinded variable: $group

Comment: Can you briefly explain what exactly do you do after you call `vendor:publish`? Can you show me how your new template file look like?

Comment: @Haru See please: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.2/resources/views/master.blade.php

Comment: @Haru I want extend this layout to blade of translation manager.

Comment: And what did you already do to your `resources/views/vendor/translation-manager/index.blade.php` file? What did you put in `content` section? Can you show me `index.blade.php` file as well?

Comment: @Haru see please: https://pastebin.com/8ydg5VQk with this layout I get error: undifined variable group..

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want the manager's form inside your voyager theme. The first thing you shouldn't be doing here is putting everything to the `content` section. All the assets from the `laravel-translation-manager` should be added by extending sections as well.

Comment: @Haru I have section content there: https://pastebin.com/8ydg5VQk

Comment: What I meant was you should put there only manager's body, without unnecessary sections. What you're doing is basically nesting `<html>` in voyager's `<html>` - this will not work. The reason you're doing that is that you don't like how `laravel-translation-manager` is displayed, don't include it then. What you want is to put only from inside `content` section (and add some js handling to different sections).

Comment: Are you extending voyagers main template as well? Can you do some adjustments to it?

Comment: @Haru I still get undefined variable $group..

Comment: I don't know what did you do. Please, show me the snippet.